# How to I get a chef custom lwrp to implement notifies and not_if?

Tags: chef-infra, lwrp

I write a custom Lightweight resource.  But the notifies and only_if is not recognized.

Anyone else get this working?

I use these in opsworks supplies resources.  So I know I am using them correctly.
Unfortunately proprietary code, so I can't post the code.

Comment: You should select the correct answer!! or in the future maybe won't receive any help.

Answer (score 3):

Ok.  RTFM.  Well not really. I did not find this specific issue covered.
If you write your own light weight resource and want to be able to use notifies, then use

- new_resource.updated_by_last_action(false)
  or
- new_resource.updated_by_last_action(true)

  in your resource action code.

notifies will then happen (true) or not happen(false).

Answer (score 3):

Here is an example from [Opscode](http://docs.opscode.com/lwrp_custom_provider.html#updated-by-last-action)

```
action :create do
  t = template "/etc/cron.d/#{new_resource.name}" do
    cookbook new_resource.cookbook
    source "cron.d.erb"
    mode "0644"
    variables({
        :name => new_resource.name,
        :minute => new_resource.minute,
        :hour => new_resource.hour,
        :day => new_resource.day,
        :month => new_resource.month,
        :weekday => new_resource.weekday,
        :command => new_resource.command,
        :user => new_resource.user,
        :mailto => new_resource.mailto,
        :path => new_resource.path,
        :home => new_resource.home,
        :shell => new_resource.shell
      })
    action :create
  end
  new_resource.updated_by_last_action(t.updated_by_last_action?)
end
```

If you want to research more deep just follow the link.

Answer (score 0):

Seemingly, the solution mentioned by @Robert never worked, as mentioned in Chef issue [#3748](https://github.com/chef/chef/issues/3748). A working solution would be to use 'use_inline_resources'.